# Notifying Redux store of React UI errors

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, redux

In a Redux/React application I used the lifecycle method `componentDidCatch()` to catch and handle errors during rendering of the React UI. Is there a way to automatically notify the Redux store of the errors caught there, without necessarily dispatching an action?

Comment: If your question has been answered; please mark it as such.

Comment: No. The store is designed to be updated via dispatched actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would definitely need to dispatch an action, but you can write an error filter around your top level component. For example let's say your entire app is wrapped in a `<Home>` app  tag. In your home component you can use your `componentDidCatch` to send your errors to redux just one time for your entire project (because React will bubble the exception to the top level). The granularity in which you utilize `componentDidCatch` or Error Boundaries is up to you, but at a minimum...a single handler with a single dispatch at the top level should suffice.